# List only commands with lsof

Tags: lsof

I tried with

```
lsof -F c somefile
```

But I get

```
p1
cinit
p231
cmountall
p314
cupstart-udev-br
p317
cudevd
```

Instead of

```
init
mountall
...
```

Any way to get just the command?

Comment: idk what do you mean by that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man page says procces ID is always selected.

depending on your need, you may use awk to filter out process

```
lsof -F c somefile | awk '/^c/ { print substr($0,2)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

This will select lines that begin with the `c` tag and print them out after removing the  tag.

```
lsof -F c somefile | sed -n 's/^c//p'
```

Comment: I undeleted this since it is a perfectly good answer and indeed much simpler than using `awk`. If you _really_ want to remove it I promise I won't undelete again but please leave it.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I saw it was a dup of a comment (by @Stéphane Chazelas , I think) and wanted to let the commenter post it as an answer.

Comment: Answers posted as comments are fair game. If you want to be polite, you can mention the comment but [it is perfectly fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157889/203101) to post as an answer something that someone else posted as a comment. Especially if you flesh it out a bit as you have done.